# How to delete Excel.Name object?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, vsto, excel-2007, excel-2003

I have a bunch of Excel.Name objects under Workbook.Names collection which contain invalid references.  In other words, when I evaluate the Excel.Name.RefersTo property, I get a value back beginning with "=#REF...". I tried to run the following code but it seems to have no effect in removing the names:

```
var ranges = myWorkBook.Names;
for (int i = 1; i <= ranges.Count; i++)
{
    var currentName = ranges.Item(i, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    var refersTo = currentName.RefersTo.ToString();
    if (refersTo.Contains("REF!"))
    {
        currentName.Delete();
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong here?  Or maybe I'm missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMissico led me in the right direction.  `currentName.Delete()` definitely does not work.  However there is no support for Workbook.Names[i].Delete under VSTO 2005 SE, so I dug around some more and discovered that `Workbook.Names.Item(i, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)` did the trick.

This is an example of the code that will work:

```
var ranges = myWorkBook.Names;

int i = 1;
while (i <= ranges.Count)
{
    var currentName = ranges.Item(i, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    var refersTo = currentName.RefersTo.ToString();
    if (refersTo.Contains("REF!"))
    {
        ranges.Item(i, Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Delete();
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tested this. It works, but do note that if you have named ranges for workbook and sheet which are otherwise identical, calling delete on the workbook scoped name index will delete the sheet scoped name instead. I haven't found a way around this other than deleting the sheet scope range first.

Answer (score 3):

To delete using the name:

```
workbook.Names.Item(rangeName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing).Delete();
```

(in C# that is).

Answer (score 1):

Try `Workbook.Names[i].Delete()`. You cannot used `currentName.Delete`. (From memory, I will try to find my code to do this.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and let you know how it turned out.

Comment: in the end it was Workbook.Names.Item(i, Type.Missing, Type.Missing) that did the trick.  Thanks for pointing me in the right path!

Comment: @code4life: Ah, that is right. Have to call `Item` because it is a COM call.

Answer (score 1):

I came accross the problem that when you delete a bunch of names from the active workbook, the index of the Names collection gets updated immediately. This may cause bad index/index out of range exception.

If you want to be sure to delete all available Names, use this code:

```
public void finalize()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook myWorkbook = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;


        var ranges = myWorkbook.Names;
        int leftoveritems;
        leftoveritems = ranges.Count;

        while (leftoveritems > 0)
        {
            int i = 1;
            try
            {
                while (i <= leftoveritems)
                {
                    myWorkbook.Names.Item(i).Delete();
                    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(i + " deleted.");
                    i++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(i + " failed " + ex.Message);
            }

            ranges = myWorkbook.Names;
            leftoveritems = ranges.Count;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just set it up as a VBA function and then called it from C#:

**VBA** (can uncomment the one line if you want to delete only the ref error named ranges):

```
Sub DeleteNamedRanges()
   Dim nm As Object
   Dim mystr As String

   For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
      On Error Resume Next
      'If InStr(1, nm.RefersTo, "#REF!") Then
      nm.Delete
      On Error GoTo 0
   Next
End Sub
```

C#:

```
XlApp.Application.Run($"'{fileName}'!{yourWorksheet.CodeName}.DeleteNamedRanges");
```

Note on the C#, in my case, I was putting that VBA into a specific worksheet's code, because I was copying that worksheet into other workbooks and I wanted it accessible in those workbooks so I had to call the fully qualified path to the VBA method. It would be much simpler, if you don't need something like that, to just put the VBA code into ThisWorkbook or a module and call it more directly.

Comment: I'd have to inject the VBA into the target workbook, then invoke it... Surely there must be an easier way to do this.

Comment: If you're creating a workbook purely from scratch (i.e. in C# code only, without using a wb template or without copying anything from an existing/open workbook) then yes, not the best. But if you already have a template, or a worksheet you know you'll be copying, it makes it very easy to just include the VBA code up-front and you'll know it will be there for your calling.